# What setting do I need on my digital clamp meter?

Tags: electrical, pump

I bought a digital clamp meter to test the points on my submersible pump which runs off 220.

What do I need to set the meter on?

Comment: batteries ... turn it to ON

Comment: Well most people that use so-called "220" actually use 230V or 240V.  If you have a meter with a choice of ranges and one of them is 200, that's too low. You need the 2000V range.  The reason we call it "220" is the same reason we call it Kleenex or Xerox.  It was actually 220V a century ago when they started selling electricity to the masses.

Comment: any number higher then 200 Volt (on the AC side)

Comment: It is comonly known as 220 Volt, even if it is not

Comment: Most modern clamp style MMs are self calibrating.  on mine I just set it for A/C and it gets it, there are no range settings... yours might be different, but this is just a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Harper wrong analogy. More like people who called a refrigerator an icebox ln the late 20th century. My grandparents used to call the refrigerator the Frigidaire even when it was GE or something else - that's like kleenex or Xerox.